# Producing a $G$-invariant form from the standard Hermitian product using the averaging process

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> **Problem statement**: Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $3$. The matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 \\ 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ has order $3$, so it defines a matrix representation of $G$. Use the averaging process to produce a $G$-invariant form from the standard Hermitian product $\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{y}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

So I am working on this proof and I am still confused what exactly the problem statement means when it says "$G$-invariant form from the standard Hermitian product $\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{y}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$".

I understand that the form is defined by the inner product, but am I just supposed to find the $G$-invariant vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

I know that $$A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 \\ 1 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ -1 && -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and then we have eigenvectors for $A$ and $A^2$ respectively
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -1 +\sqrt{3}i \\ 2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -1 -\sqrt{3}i \\ 2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 +\sqrt{3}i \\ -2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 -\sqrt{3}i \\ -2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

So, clearly the space

$$\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 +\sqrt{3}i \\ -2\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

is $G$-invariant. I am confused how I use the averaging process to find my form? I don't understand how the sum

$$\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\{g\mathbf{x}, g\mathbf{y}\}$$

is interpreted in this formula. My book says $\{\ , \}$ represents a positive definite form, so $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{y} > 0$, but I am just unsure where to go from here. In this case, we would have $$\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1, A^i \in G}^{3}\{A^i\mathbf{x}, A^i\mathbf{y}\},$$ but I don't understand how to interpret this. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Finding $G$-invariant vectors in not what you are asked to do. You are given a pairing $\{\cdot, \cdot\}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (the standard hermitian form on $\mathbb{C}^2$) and you want to find a $G$-invariant pairing $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$. In order to do this, you use the formula towards the end of your post.

We have a faithful two-dimensional complex representation $\rho : \mathbb{Z}_3 \to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $1 \mapsto A$. So $\rho(0) = I$, $\rho(1) = A$, and $\rho(2) = A^2$; i.e. $\rho(i) = A^i$. With this representation at hand, we obtain $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$, a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $\varphi(i, v) = \rho(i)v$.

The correction interpretation of the formula is then

$$\langle x, y\rangle = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_3}\{\rho(i)x, \rho(i)y\} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}_3}\{A^ix, A^iy\} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^2\{A^ix, A^iy\}.$$

Now note that $\{x, y\} = x^*y = \bar{x}^Ty$, so

$$\langle x, y\rangle = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^2\{A^ix, A^iy\} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^2\overline{A^ix}^TA^iy = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^2\bar{x}^T(A^i)^TA^iy = \bar{x}^T\left(\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=0}^2 (A^i)^TA^i\right)y.$$

So $\langle x, y\rangle = \bar{x}^TBy$ where $B = \frac{1}{3}(I + A^TA + (A^2)^TA^2)$.

Comment: Ohh, I see. This makes more sense now. But I guess my confusion now is whether or not I need to define vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, or do I just define the matrix $B$ by the formula? Or from here do I find a $B$-invariant vectors? Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Or am I simply showing that $$\langle x,y \rangle=\bar{x}^TAy$$ by using the averaging formula?

Comment: You do not need to define vectors $x$ and $y$. The form $\langle\ ,\rangle$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3$-invariant if $\langle x, y\rangle = \langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \langle A^2x, A^2y\rangle$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^2$. If you compute $B$, the form $\langle x, y\rangle = \bar{x}^TBy$ will be $\mathbb{Z}_3$-invariant as you can check.

Comment: Oh this makes sense, because if you compute $\langle x,y \rangle=\bar{x}^TBy$, $\langle Ax,Ay \rangle=(\bar{A}\bar{x})^TBAy$, and $\langle A^{2}x,A^{2}y \rangle=(\bar{A}^{2}\bar{x})^TBA^{2}y$, you will get the same value for the form (I just computed $\bar{x}^TBy$ and $\bar{Ax}^TBAy$ and got the same result. So a $G$-invariant form means that $G$ can act on the form $\langle x,y \rangle$, and the form will not change?

Comment: Well, $G$ acts on $x$ and $y$ (in this case by multiplication by $A^i$), but yes. The form $\langle\ , \rangle$ gives the same value whether evaluated on $x$ and $y$ or $A^ix$ and $A^iy$.